# ¿Cómo exportar modulos correctamente en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modular, javascript-import

Estoy intentando exportar un módulo pero no lo consigo, cada vez que intento algo me da un error diferente. Lo estoy haciendo de estas formas peo no hay manera.

**EN MI ARCHIVO INDEX.HTML:**

```
<script charset="UTF-8" **type="module"** src="main.js" ></script>
```

**EN MI ARCHIVO MAIN.JS:**

```
import MyClass from './my_class.js';
```

**EN MI ARCHIVO MY_CLASS.JS:**

Este archivo es que que me está dando la lata. Basicamente lo he intendado hacer de todas las formas que se dice [aquí](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_modules-in-javascript), pero ninguna de ellas me funciona.

'use strict';

**Prueba1**

```
export default class MyClass
{
}

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export*
```

**Prueba 2**

```
class MyClass
{
}

export default MyClass;

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export*
```

**Prueba 3**

```
class MyClass
{
}
module.exports =  MyClass;

*Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './my_class.js' does not provide an export named 'default'*
```

¿Aguien sabe cómo hacer esto correctamente?

Comment: Hola, ¿has revisado compatibilidad del navegador?

Comment: La verdad es que no... no sé como hacerlo... pero estoy usando la última versión de Chrome pienso que debería funcionar... pero ahora que me comentas esto no sé si voy a querer trabajar así... la verdad es que me interesa que no existan incompatibilidades :-(

Comment: Tienes muchas opciones, todas dependen de lo que estés haciendo. Puedes revisar [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org), otra cosa que puedes hacer es transpilar con [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io). Incluso puedes crear una app de escritorio multiplataforma usando [ElectronJS](https://electronjs.org)

Comment: Ok, gracias!! Le doy un vistazo a esas opciones!!